# Visual Studio Community showing 30 day evaluation trial

Tags: visual-studio

[image]

if visual studio community free So why does this message appear to me?

Comment: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/support/community-edition-expired-buy-license/

Comment: I've removed your irrelevant tags, since this question isn't related to C#, C++, or Python.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a false premise (free commercial software does not have restrictions).

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to buy a license to use the Community edition of Visual Studio.

You might just need to sign in with your Microsoft account to register your edition, but no payment is needed.

**Source:** https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/support/community-edition-expired-buy-license/

Comment: I was already signed in but my licence showed that it was expiring. All I had to do was click "Check for an updated licence" and once again all is good with the world.